# Proving a limit of the floor function

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove by the definition of the limit

$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{5}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor} = 0$

(If you use that for every $x \in R, x-1 \leq \lfloor{x}\rfloor \leq x$, prove it).

I did the following:

$ |f(x) - L| = | \frac{5}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor} | = - \frac{5}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor} \leq - \frac{5}{x} < - \frac{5}{M} = \epsilon $

So $M= - \frac{5}{\epsilon}$

But it seems too obvious. Also I didn't know how to prove the definition of the floor function.

Is it correct?

Comment: Use squeeze theorem.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz We haven't studied it yet

Comment: The limit part is correct. What is the definition of the floor function? I thought $\lfloor x \rfloor \le x$ is part of the definition (largest integer not exceeding $x$)